# Prove that you need to add $1/3$ of the edges in a graph with $n > 3$ vertices to make it complete by the binomial coefficient?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we have a complete graph with $ > 3$ vertices and theoretically want to make it triangle free, to do this we should remove at least $1/3$ of the initial amount of edges? Now I am thinking about the reverse of this question – how can I mathematically prove/show that we would need to add $1/3$ of the removed edges back to make it complete again? In my previous question, I mentioned that I wanted to solve the problem using the binomial coefficient with $B(n,2)= n(n-1)/2$ where $1$ edge $= (n-2)$ triangles.

Comment: Please add a link to your previous question.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you meant, but surely to make it a complete graph (with all the original vertices) you need to put back **all** of the removed edges.  That is, by definition a graph that is missing an edge between two vertices is not a complete graph.

Comment: Hey, thank you for having commented. The issue is that I need to mathematically prove how that would work (with the binomial coefficient). We proved in class that we need to remove at least 1/3 of the amount of initial edges of a graph with n > 3 vertices but the question left in the end was: can we reverse/invert the whole process?

Comment: As it stands, your assertion "we proved in class that we need to remove at least 1/3 of the amount of initial edges of a graph [to make it triangle free]" is not true. For the complete graph, we need to remove 1/2 of the edges to make it triangle free, but for a graph with only 1 triangle but many edges, we only need to remove 1 edge. Please elaborate on what you have done and what you want to do (in full detail).